# JSP Spring Hibernate not showing the ${} list

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I have issue with listing my database output, following code does not print the list of names(it seems like contactList is empty):

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!--- a lot of code blahblah

--->
<div class="row">
    <form:form method="post" action="add" commandName="contact" modelAttribute="contact">

        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="firstname"><spring:message code="label.firstname"/></form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="lastname"><spring:message code="label.lastname"/></form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="lastname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="email"><spring:message code="label.email"/></form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="telephone"><spring:message code="label.telephone"/></form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="telephone" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.addcontact"/>"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
    </form:form>
</div>
<div class="row">

<table class="table table-hover">

<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Telephone</th>
    <th>###</th>
</tr>




<c:forEach var="contact" items="${contactList}" >
    <tr>
        <td>${contact.lastname}, ${contact.firstname} </td>
        <td>${contact.email}</td>
        <td>${contact.telephone}</td>
        <td><a href="delete/${contact.id}">delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>



</table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/","/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)


public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> model) {
        List<Contact> list = contactService.listContact();

        for ( Contact contact : (List<Contact>) list ) {
            System.out.println( "Contact (" + contact.getFirstname() + ") : " + contact.getTelephone() );
        }

        model.put("contactList", list); 
        model.put("contact", new Contact());



        return "contact";
    }
```

it is worth noting, that the list is not empty inside the controller, as it outputs those:

```
Contact (tomku) : 420
Contact (dud) : 560
Contact () : 11
Contact (mac) : 22
Contact () : 3232
```

pom.xml

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.programcreek</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>HelloWorld Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>  

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>



       <!--  SPRING DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>HelloWorld</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

what could cause the issue?

**EDIT:**
changing controller to this one did not solve the problem

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
public ModelAndView listContacts(Map<String,Object> model) {


List<Contact> list = contactService.listContact();

for ( Contact contact : (List<Contact>) list ) {
    System.out.println( "Contact (" + contact.getFirstname() + ") : " + contact.getTelephone() );
}

model.put("contactList", list); 
model.put("contact", new Contact());


return new ModelAndView("contact",model);
}
```

EDIT2: 
[image]

Comment: Just a note: implementing deletion with a hyperlink doing a GET request is really something you shouldn't do. This, for example, will cause Google to delete every contact when it crawls your page. Get is used to GET data? Not to delete data. Use a form.

Answer (score 0):

Try using A Spring MVC Model as your model object ala:

```
@RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
public String helloWorld(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!");
    return "helloWorld";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to make below changes.

1 .In your spring controller,change return statement  like below.

```
return new ModelAndView("contact","model",model);
```

2. In JSP change the `c:forEach` tag like below.

```
<c:forEach var="contact" items="${model.contactList}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jsp is perfectly fine but 
In your controller class you need Object of Class  [ModelMap](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html)

Refactoring your Controller Class :

```
public String listContacts(ModelMap model) {
        List<Contact> list = contactService.listContact();

 for ( Contact contact : (List<Contact>) list ) {
System.out.println( "Contact (" + contact.getFirstname() + ") : " + contact.getTelephone() );
        }

        model.addAttribute("contactList", list); 
        model.addAttribbute("contact", new Contact());
        return "contact";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same type of problem in which I put list inside ModelAndView object and tried to show that list on jsp page using foreach loop.

I have exhausted my 2 hours, but search and found that adding

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

solved my problem, please try this.